# Send comma seperated values to function as a single parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I am trying to send comma separated values from controller to model method in a single parameter.

For example, there is a function in model:

```
public function bar($param1){
//....///
  $this->datatables->edit_column($param1);
//....///
}
```

and from controller I am trying to send a param like:

```
   public function foo(){
   //...//
    $param = "'username', '<a href="profiles/edit/$1">$2</a>', 'id, username'";
    $this->model->bar($param);
   //...//
   }
```

And the first top problem I am facing is that I know only of two characters `''` and `""` because of which I can't send this as proper string, not good with escaping also.

Plus I think what I am trying it will be sent as string inside that function but edit_column required 3 different comma separated values.

Below is my whole Datatables Common Model which uses Ignited Data-tables Library:

```
//Common DataTables Queries
function select_fields_joined_DT($data, $PTable, $joins = '', $where = '',$group_by = '', $addColumn = '', $editColumn = '',$unsetColumn = '')
{
    $this->datatables->select($data);
    if ($unsetColumn != '') {
        $this->datatables->unset_column($unsetColumn);
    }
    $this->datatables->from($PTable);
    if ($joins != '') {
        foreach ($joins as $k => $v) {
            $this->datatables->join($v['table'], $v['condition'], $v['type']);
        }
    }
    if ($where != '') {
        $this->datatables->where($where);
    }
    if($group_by != ''){
        $this->datatables->group_by($group_by);
    }
    if ($addColumn != '') {
        $this->datatables->add_column("Actions", $addColumn);
    }
    if ($editColumn != ''){
        $this->datatables->edit_column($editColumn);
    }
    $result = $this->datatables->generate();
    return $result;
}
//End of Common DataTables Queries
```

I'm stuck inside edit_column function of datatables.

The edit_column is suppose to be like:

```
$this->datatables->edit_column('username', '<a href="profiles/edit/$1">$2</a>', 'id, username');
```

I am just wondering how can I send different values separated by commas in single parameter? Or do I just have to send as array or something?

Here is the variable where I am trying to save three comma separated values:

```
$editColumn = "\'employee.employee_id\',\'<a href=\"dashboard_site/view_skills/$1\"><span class=\"fa fa-eye\"></span></a>\',\'employee.employee_id\'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify this way

```
$editColumn = "'employee.employee_id','<a href=\"dashboard_site/view_skills/$1\"><span class=\"fa fa-eye\"></span></a>','employee.employee_id'";
```

it will produce the string like this

```
'employee.employee_id','<a href="dashboard_site/view_skills/$1"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>','employee.employee_id'
```

You can do it alternative way.Send the data as array and convert them at your model.